# ObjectId not updating on MongoDB - Node.Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to update my "ObjectId" from front-end to my database but apparently its not updating. If I add a new data from the ui to the db, it works great... however it doesnt when I want to update that data.

I've tried mostly everything but it doesn't seem to be working. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks

This is my server.js code:

```js
    let express = require('express')
let MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
let ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;


let app = express()
let db
app.use(express.static('public'))

let connectionString = "mongodb+srv://todoAppUser:(HIDDEN)/TodoAPP?retryWrites=true"
MongoClient.connect(connectionString, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true}, function(err, client) {
  db = client.db()
  app.listen(3000)

})
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}))

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  db.collection('items').find().toArray(function(err, items) {
    res.send(`<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Simple To-Do App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="display-4 text-center py-1">To-Do App</h1>

      <div class="jumbotron p-3 shadow-sm">
        <form action="/create-item" method="POST">
          <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
            <input name="item" autofocus autocomplete="off" class="form-control mr-3" type="text" style="flex: 1;">
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Add New Item</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>

      <ul class="list-group pb-5">
        ${items.map(function(item) {
          return `<li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
            <span class="item-text">${item.text}</span>
            <div>
              <button data-id="${item._id}" class="edit-me btn btn-secondary btn-sm mr-1">Edit</button>
              <button class="delete-me btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
            </div>
          </li>`
        }).join('')}
      </ul>

    </div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="/browser.js"></script>


  </body>
  </html>`)
  })

})

app.post('/create-item', function(req, res) {
  db.collection('items').insertOne({text: req.body.item}, function() {
    res.redirect('/')
  })

})

app.post('/update-item', function(req, res) {
  db.collection('items').findOneAndUpdate({_id: new mongodb.ObjectId(req.body.id)}, {$set: {text: req.body.text}}, function() {
    res.send("Success")
  })
})
```

and this is my browser.js

```js
   document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains("edit-me")) {
    let userInput = prompt("Enter your desired new text")
      axios.post('/update-item', {text: userInput, _id: e.target.getAttribute("data-id")}).then(function () {
        // do something interesting here in the next video
      }).catch(function() {
        console.log("Please try again later.")
      })
    }
})
```

I appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: The `update-item` api is just `finding` an entry with the objectId specified, and then updating the text field here `{$set: {text: req.body.text}}`. You aren't updating the ObjectId anyway above.

Comment: I'm not really sure where to go from there. Could you guide me? What should I add next? Thanks

Comment: if your intention is to update the `text` key data for the specified objectId, I think it should work fine. Can you check if the id being received in the update function exists in the database or not?

Comment: Well, yes it does =>   _id: ObjectId("60f7f9ffaa47de1e94be9dd6")
                                     text: "buy apples"

Comment: Ok I believe this is the problem, `{_id: new mongodb.ObjectId(req.body.id)}`. This should actually be `{_id: ObjectId(req.body.id)}` since you are already importing the ObjectId on top. Try it, and also try `console.log(new mongodb.ObjectId(req.body.id))` and `console.log(ObjectId(req.body.id))`. The outputs should explain everything.

Comment: It's not updating again... the output => new ObjectId("60f863a41c2bcf21ad2a7fc8")

Comment: Can you please add the output of all these here: 
`console.log(req.body.id)`,
`console.log(new mongodb.ObjectId(req.body.id))` ,
`console.log(ObjectId(req.body.id))`

Comment: I fixed it! I appreciate your help. I'm not sure which one worked because I tried bunch of other methods but thanks anyway.

Comment: thats awesome..

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same problem and this solution worked for for me. it will be like this

```
app.post('/update-item', function(req, res) {
db.collection('items').findOneAndUpdate({_id: ObjectId(req.body.id)}, {$set: {text: req.body.text}}, function() {
  res.send("Success")
})
```

})

instead of

```
app.post('/update-item', function(req, res) {
  db.collection('items').findOneAndUpdate({_id: new mongodb.ObjectId(req.body.id)}, {$set: {text: req.body.text}}, function() {
    res.send("Success")
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
  
let ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;

//Replace the above line of code with the one below

let mongodbObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;

//Also, do the same for this line of code (use 'new mongodbObjectId' instead of 'new mongodb.ObjectId') as shown below

db.collection('items').findOneAndUpdate({_id: new mongodbObjectId(req.body.id)}, {$set: {text: req.body.text}}, function() {
        res.send("Success")
```

Comment: Try and include some of those comments outside of the code as well